# Quadratic Formula in Python

Tags: python

Here is my quadratic formula code. You enter in the full equation, and it outputs the roots. The problem is, my code fully depends on the index spot of where the number is in the list, and if I were to miss a space somewhere while writing my code, it would not work. Anyone know how to fix this?

```
import re
import cmath

quadratic = str(input('Enter a quadratic equation (in the form of ax^2 + bx + c): '))

split_qua = re.split(' | x |', quadratic)

a1 = (split_qua[1])
b1 = (split_qua[8])
c1 = (split_qua[13])

a = int(a1)
b = int(b1)
c = int(c1)

def roots(a,b,c):
    dis = b*b-4*a*c
    if dis >=0:
        root1 =(-b + cmath.sqrt(dis) / 2*a)
        root2 =(-b - cmath.sqrt(dis) / 2*a)
        return root1, root2
    elif dis < 0:
        return 'This does not work. There is no roots'

print(roots(a,b,c))
```

Comment: That's not the right way to solve your problem.  You need to parse that string, character by character.  Gather up digits until you get an 'x'.  Ignore all spaces.  That way, you can handle + or -.

Comment: It could be noted too that an _equation_ needs an equal sign. So you're probably meaning `ax^2 + bx + c = 0`.

Comment: oh didn't even realize lol. Thanks

Comment: I have made one where I took coefficients as input, and that one worked fine. This was a challenge from one of my friends

Answer (score 0):

You could try removing all the spaces and then parsing your input string:

```
a,b,c = map(int, [s.split("x")[0] for s in quadratic.replace(" ","").split("+")])
```

Comment: This would need to deal with coefficients equal to 1 where it's not explicit, such as in `x^2 + 2x + 2`, and also will raise an exception when one coefficient is absent such as `x^2 + 2x`

Comment: OP is casting each of `a` `b` and `c` to `int` so clearly there is no input validation.

Answer (score 0):

Here's a brute force parser that ignores spaces and handles signs and floats.  It will also handle missing values (`3x^2-9`).

```
def parse_equation(s):
    nums = [0,0,0]
    accum = ''
    expo = False
    sign = 1
    for c in s:
        if expo and c == '2':
            expo = False
            nums[0] = nums[1]
            nums[1] = 0
            accum = ''
        elif c in '1234567890.':
            accum += c
        elif c == 'x':
            nums[1] = float(accum) * sign
            accum = ''
        elif c == '+':
            sign = 1
        elif c == '-':
            sign = -1
        elif c == '^':
            expo = True
    nums[2] = float(accum) * sign
    return nums

for test in (
    '3x^2+4x-3',
    '3x^2 + 4x - 3',
    '-19.5 x^2 + 7.5 x - 3'
):
    print(test, parse_equation(test))
```

Output:

```
3x^2+4x-3 [3.0, 4.0, -3.0]
3x^2 + 4x - 3 [3.0, 4.0, -3.0]
-19.5 x^2 + 7.5 x - 3 [-19.5, 7.5, -3.0]
```

Answer (score 0):

You can extract the numbers and check the equation structure in one [regex expression](https://regex101.com/r/nYTdBw/1)

```
import re
import cmath

quadratic = str(input('Enter a quadratic equation (in the form of ax^2 + bx + c): '))
parts = re.findall(r'(\d+)x\^2\s*\+\s*(\d+)x\s*\+\s*(\d+)', quadratic)

try:
    a, b, c = [int(x) for x in parts[0]]
except:
    raise RuntimeError('Incorrect equation')


def roots(a, b, c):
    dis = b * b - 4 * a * c
    if dis >= 0:
        root1 = (-b + cmath.sqrt(dis) / 2 * a)
        root2 = (-b - cmath.sqrt(dis) / 2 * a)
        return root1, root2
    elif dis < 0:
        return 'This does not work. There is no roots'


print(roots(a, b, c))
```

Output:

```
Enter a quadratic equation (in the form of ax^2 + bx + c): 4x^2 + 8x + 1
((5.8564064605510175+0j), (-21.856406460551018+0j))
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do like this.

- Remove the spaces from the input using `.replace()`
- Split the string at `+` to get individual strings.

  ```
  a,b,c = quadratic.replace(" ","").split('+')
  ```
- Strip off the powers of `x` from the individual strings using
  `rstrip()` and convert them to Integers.

  ```
  a = int(a.rstrip('x^2'))
  b = int(b.rstrip('x'))
  c = int(c)
  ```

Here is the full code:

```
import cmath

quadratic = str(input('Enter a quadratic equation (in the form of ax^2 + bx + c): '))

a,b,c = quadratic.replace(" ","").split('+')

a = int(a.rstrip('x^2'))
b = int(b.rstrip('x'))
c = int(c)

def roots(a,b,c):
    dis = b*b-4*a*c
    if dis >=0:
        root1 =(-b + cmath.sqrt(dis) / 2*a)
        root2 =(-b - cmath.sqrt(dis) / 2*a)
        return root1, root2
    elif dis < 0:
        return 'This does not work. There is no roots'

print(roots(a,b,c))
```

Answer (score 0):

You're running into a problem with your regular expression on this line:

```
split_qua = re.split(' | x |', quadratic)
```

I'm not entirely sure how you came up with that regex, but it's effectively splitting the string in any of the following situations:

1. Between spaces
2. Between any occurrence of the string `" x "` (that's an "x" with a space on either side)
3. Between all characters

Situation #3 is always going to win.

Without getting too much into the syntax of regular expressions--a topic that you may want to research on your own--all of the characters in your regex are being taken literally except the vertical bar (`|`).  That is effectively acting as an "or" operator: split between `" "` *or* `" x "` *or* `""`.  That last one is giving you trouble.

The ideal solution here would be to parse everything properly rather than using regular expressions; however, since this is likely just a quick script for personal use, you can certainly craft a better regex.  It won't be ideal, but it'll likely work well enough for your purposes.  For example:

```
split_qua = re.fullmatch(r'([+-]?\d+)?x\^2([+-]\d+)?x([+-]\d+)?', quadratic.replace(' ', ''))

a = int(split_qua[1] or 1)
b = int(split_qua[2] or 1)
c = int(split_qua[3] or 0)
```

Let's break down the regex:

1. This isn't actually part of the regex, but notice that we're calling replace() to remove all the whitespace.  This just allows us to use a simpler regex, since we don't need to worry about parsing spaces.
2. Each number in which we're interested is parsed via `([+-]?\d+)` or `([+-]\d+)`.  The first one is used when we don't know whether there will be a sign; that only happens for `a`.

   1. The parentheses are used for grouping; the first set of parentheses will be stored in `split_qua[1]` and so on.
   2. `[+-]` means "either `+` or `-`"
   3. `?` means the previous token is optional--in this case, it means the sign is optional
   4. `\d` means "any digit"
   5. `+` means "repeated one or more times," that way we can have numbers that are more than one digit long
3. `x` matches the literal character "x"
4. `\^` matches the literal character "^".  Carets have a special meaning in regular expressions, so we have to escape them.
5. The `?` following clothing parenthesis of each group indicates that it's optional.  If `a` or `b` are omitted, we'll assume their value is `1`; if `c` is omitted, we'll assume its value is `0`.

This technique is far from perfect: in particular, it can't parse expressions in which one of the first two terms is omitted.  For example, `3x^2 + 1` will fail to parse.  It's up to you whether this is worth handling; if it is, you should investigate using proper parsing logic rather than regular expressions.  If this doesn't matter to you, the regular expression here may be sufficient.